# Chain (compose) method calls in Groovy

Tags: groovy, clojure

I have a variable and several methods I'd like to call in a sequence where return value of one method is an input of another. Basically a pipeline. Now, is there a way of chaining the calls? In a pseudo code it looks like

```
def a = [1, 2, 3]
def b = calculation3(calculation2(calculation1(a)))
```

As you can see it looks very Clojure-like and I'd like to end up with something like (using Clojure syntax)

```
(-> a 
   calculation1
   calculation2
   calculation3)
```

I was hoping to use the `with` keyword but it only passes the variable `a` around not collecting the results and passing them as the input to the next method.

The only working solution I've found so far is 'closure composition' like this. But that seems to be too heavy handed to me.

```
def a = [1, 2, 3]
def b = (class1.&calculation1 >> class1.&calculation2 >> class1.&calculation3)(a)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Use Clojure instead? :)

Comment: I'd love to but the project I'm working on is Groovy/Grails

Comment: The last one looks pretty close to Clojure's. When spanned across multiple lines at least.

Comment: My problem with it is that it internally generates 2 more closures.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function to do it:

```
def chain(a, Closure... fns) {
    fns.toList().inject(a) { v, c -> c(v) }
}
```

Then call this in your code:

```
chain(a, class1.&calculation1,class1.&calculation2,class1.&calculation3)
```

Answer (score 2):

I gave a bit more thought and have come up with something like this:

```
def compose = {...c ->
   {result ->
      c.each {
         result = it(result)
      }
   result
   }
}

def a = [1, 2, 3]
def b = compose(class1.&calculation1, class1.&calculation2, class1.&calculation3)(a)
```

Still it's not as nice as Clojure's threading.

Comment: Neat.  It's a pity Groovy requires all the `Foo.&func` or `this.&func` noise. If foo() can be resolved to a direct method call (assuming it exists) then `&foo` (or something similar) ought to be able to resolve to a method reference without the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Use `inject`

```
def pipe(fn, ...fns) {
    { args ->
        fns.inject(fn(args)) { acc, value ->
            value(acc)
        }
    }
}
```

Not that the first function is allowed to take a variable number of arguments while the following parameters are not.